# Write to external Hadoop with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using Java-Spark.

I'm trying to write to external HDFS directory as follow:

```
df.write().mode(mode).save("hdfs://myservername:8020/user/path/to/hdfs");
```

And got an exception

> host details: local host is: ... destination host is: ...

How can I write to "external" hdfs directory from Spark and not to local Hadoop/HDFS?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to overwrite `fs.defaultFS` in the Spark configuration, but this looks correct

Comment: I have another way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the HDFS Namenode hostname is accessible from Spark cluster, you can either use ip address as well.

`hdfs://<HDFS_NAMENODE_IP>:8020/user/path/to/hdfs`

You can also update the spark configuration in the spark application using:

`spark.conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://<HDFS_NAMENODE_IP>:8020/")`.

Comment: Thank you!, Its override the hdfs-site.xml file or its only override the current configuration for this running??

Comment: It will override the current configuration.

Comment: Oh ok, thats meaning that I'm not override the configuration to another spark applications, right?

Comment: Yes, this configuration will change for the current spark application only. If you want to override the configuration for all the applications, you can change the entry in core-site.xml.